# using keypress event in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, keypress

i want to delete php session variable using a key press. so i used these codes,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function textsizer(e){
var evtobj=window.event? event : e 
var unicode=evtobj.charCode? evtobj.charCode : evtobj.keyCode
var actualkey=String.fromCharCode(unicode)
if(actualkey=="x"){
    location.href="biling.php?cmd="+actualkey;}
}
document.onkeypress=textsizer
</script>
<?php if(isset($_GET['cmd'])){
unset($_SESSION["bill_array"]);
header('location:biling.php');
}
?> }
```

but the problem is, this code also clearing the session when i'm typing "x" in a text box. so i just want to stop that and clear the session only when i press "x" out side of a text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can edit your existing function as such:

```
function textsizer(e) {
    var evtobj=window.event? event : e;
    var element = evtobj.target ? evtobj.target : evtobj.srcElement;
    if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() == "body") {
        var unicode=evtobj.charCode? evtobj.charCode : evtobj.keyCode;
        var actualkey=String.fromCharCode(unicode)
        if(actualkey=="x"){
            location.href="biling.php?cmd="+actualkey;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `e.target` property to identify which element trigger the `keypress` event.

```
//Does not work on IE
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){ console.log(e.target) }, false)
```

Taking action when `e.target.tagName == 'BODY'` is a good choice.

---

### Update

For more info about `Event`, check:

- Firefox & Webkit, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event
- IE, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535863(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: For IE, I believe that would be `window.attachEvent("onkeypress", function() { ... })`

Comment: i'm not good in javascript so i used your code this way, but it is not working. so need a correction :( sorry...
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){ console.log(e.target) }, false);
if(e.target.tagName == 'BODY') {
var evtobj=window.event? event : e 
var unicode=evtobj.charCode? evtobj.charCode : evtobj.keyCode
var actualkey=String.fromCharCode(unicode)
if(actualkey=="x"){
 location.href="biling.php?cmd="+actualkey;}
}

Answer (score -1):

$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(){

});

Comment: There's no jquery tag on this. Yasitha is probably not using it.